# How to invoke dll method on a different machine?

Tags: c#, c, dll, com, dllimport

Let's say I have a C dll with functions like:

```
void beep();
char* foo(char** whatever);
```

Now I want to be able to put this dll on one machine (server) and call it from a different machine (client). The client can be C# but the dll (and proxy server) needs to be regular C. The ideal would be something like this on the client:

```
MyDllAccess remote = ProxyLib.GetRemoteDll("192.168.1.10:12100", "mydll.dll"); 
remote.execute("beep"); // other machine beeps (uses GetProcAddress to find function)
```

I know I'm reinventing COM, etc, but..... is there a way? If not, why not and what is the simplest way to do what I want since I already have the dll?

EDIT: It also needs to work with Linux shared library, e.g. ProxyLib.GetRemote("192.168.10.12100", "mything.so")

Comment: So why don't you just use DCOM for that?

Comment: I also need it to work on Linux. Adding to question.

Comment: CORBA, then.  You should have some sort of toolkit managing authentication for you.

Comment: CORBA seems overly complicated. I don't want IDL. I'll just be careful and the proxy can take care of differences in marshalling.

Comment: Maybe you could use XMLRPC? There's [xml-rpc.net](http://xml-rpc.net/) and probably several C/C++ implementations out there (i.e. [http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/])

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to work across different OSes, you will have hard time doing it in a pretty generic manner. You can search for "platform independent APIs" in this wikipedia article: [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to get an idea. Most of what you will find is heavyweight.

One simple way would be to write an ad-hoc [HTTP REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) server (possibly with [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml) as the interchange format). It has the advantage of being simple, and you will be able to access it using any OS with a decent HTTP stack (including mobiles).